# how to start te select element in alignment with the label in form

Tags: css

```css
.surveyform-class {
 background: yellow;
    margin: 0 25%;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 40px solid yellow;
}
.main-div{
 background: lightgrey;
    width: 50%;
 height:100%;
    margin: 0 25%;
    border-right: 20px solid yellow;
    border-left: 20px solid yellow;
}
form {
  /* Center the form on the page */
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
}
form >div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
form >div >div {
 padding-left: 95px;
}
label{ 
   width: 90px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
 
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <title>Survey Form</title>
 <link href="surveyform.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
<body>
<div style="    
    text-align: center;">

<h1 class="surveyform-class">Survey Form</h1>
<div class="main-div">
 lwt us know how we can improve freecode camp
<form  >
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div >
<label>
which option best describes your current role 
</label>

<select > 
<option>student</option>
<option>engineer</option>
</select>
</div>
<div >
<label>
Things that should be improved in future
</label>


<input type="checkbox" name="a">
<span> Front end projects</span>

<div>

<input type="checkbox" name="a">
<span> Backend Projects</span>
</div>
<div>


<input type="checkbox" name="a">

<span> Structure </span>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to align these select element and labels to start at same line.

Can someone help me ?

Here is jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/v650o2dL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use the css property `vertical-align:top`. Be sure to separate the containers of the left and right containers like I did below;

```css
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.yellow>h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.grey {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 200px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.input-group {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Survey Form</title>
    <link href="surveyform.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="yellow">
      <h1>Survey Form</h1>

      <div class="grey">

        <center>
          Let us know how we can improve freecode camp
        </center>

        <br>

        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
              <label>
                Which option best describes your current role 
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
              <select>
                <option>student</option>
                <option>engineer</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="left">
              <label>
                Things that should be improved in future
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="right">

              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="checkbox" name="a">
                <span> Front end projects</span>
              </div>

              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="checkbox" name="a">
                <span> Backend Projects</span>
              </div>

              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="checkbox" name="a">
                <span> Structure </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```